# Re-arrange DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the code below:

```
<div class="grp-row grp-cells-1">
    <div class="l-2c-fluid l-d-4">
        <div class="c-1">
            <label for="sometext">Label</label>
        </div>
        <div class="c-2">
            <select id="sometext" name="somename">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Option</option>
            </select>
            <p class="grp-help"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the p.grp-help to span.grp-help, rearrange the DOM, and move the span.grp-help inside the div c-1 before the label. So the final DOM will be:

```
<div class="grp-row grp-cells-1">
    <div class="l-2c-fluid l-d-4">
        <div class="c-1">
            <span class="grp-help"></span>
            <label for="sometext">Label</label>
        </div>
        <div class="c-2">
            <select id="sometext" name="somename">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Option</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to do it with jQuery?

Edit:
I've tried the following so far, but it results in duplicating the span x times in each c-1 div.

```
$("p.grp-help").replaceWith(function() { return '<span class="grp-help">' + this.innerHTML + '</span>'; });
$('span.grp-help').appendTo('div.c-1');
```

Note: the parent div (grp-row grp-cells-1) will exist multiple times, and (span grp-help) in each one will have different text, so each span must be attached to its correct parent item.

Comment: Can you post youe attempt so far? As to what you'bve tried?

Comment: Think is easier if you just remove `<p class="grp-help"></p>` before get its content and add a new `<span class="grp-help"></span>` and put content inside. Don't you?

Comment: The problem is that there's not only one instance, div.grp-row exist multiple times, and each grp-help has it's own text, so i need each span attached to it's parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this approach?

```js
var content = $('.grp-help').html();
$('.grp-help').remove();
$('.c-1').append('<span class="grp-help">' + content + '</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grp-row grp-cells-1">
  <div class="l-2c-fluid l-d-4">
    <div class="c-1">
      <label for="sometext">Label</label>
    </div>
    <div class="c-2">
      <select id="sometext" name="somename">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Option</option>
      </select>
      <p class="grp-help">bla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works for the first item only, 
if i have 3 <div class="grp-row grp-cells-1"> then it'll get the content of first span inserted into the 2nd and 3rd span 

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z5o3pxn6/

Comment: Here's one that loops with the same principle but using `.each()` in this way will likely work with your original function as well since that actually looks quite good : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOybjN?editors=001.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplication you should detach:

```
$element = $('span.grp-help');
$element.detach();
$element.appendTo('div.c-1');
```

Comment: *If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned) and a new set consisting of the inserted element is returned:*  http://api.jquery.com/appendto/