# copy class from label and add it as prop to input, and disable submit until filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am using Django, when setting field to required in Django classes, it adds "required" class to the label only (and does the validation after submitting). 
How to achieve 2 things here:
1- loop through the form, check the label if it has "required" class, and set the related input prop as required. 
2- Disable (or alert) the Submit button until all required fields are filled.

Part of the form code is below, (didn't put the whole form, because it's too long):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" id="organization_form">
  <div>
    <fieldset class="grp-module collapse">
      <div class="grp-row grp-cells-1 person_in_charge ">
        <div class="l-2c-fluid l-d-4">
          <div class="c-1">
            <label class="required" for="id_person_in_charge">
              <span class="code">P.70
              </span>Person In Charge
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="c-2">
            <input class="vTextField" id="id_person_in_charge" maxlength="255" name="person_in_charge" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grp-row grp-cells-1 position_others">
        <div class="l-2c-fluid l-d-4">
          <div class="c-1">
            <label class="required" for="id_position_others">Others
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="c-2">
            <input class="vTextField" id="id_position_others" maxlength="100" name="position_others" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: any starter javascript/jquery code please...!

Comment: Not exactly the same, but i think similar logic, see this question and the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940083/re-arrange-dom-elements i tried to modify the code to make it work, but i did not success.